# Need to replace ' with &apos;

Tags: java

Hi i am using below code to replace the single quote with the `&apos;` but it's not working could you please help me out on this?

```
String name = "Hello's";

name.replaceAll("/'/g", "&apos;");

System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: `name.replace("'", "&apos;")`. No need for regexes here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign your variable with your new value.

```
String name = "Hello's";

name = name.replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
System.out.println(name);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's not working thanks for the input

Comment: It is working, look: https://ideone.com/iDZHLB

Comment: actually it should give like Hello&apos;s

Comment: It does exactly, the output of the ideone I linked you is Hello&apos;s

Answer (score 1):

In Java, strings are immutable. `replaceAll` returns a new string and you should use that, not the original string.